# Test Class is not covered?

Tags: apex, unit-test

[image]

> this is test class for above image

```
Public static testMethod void ManualUnitTest11(){

        RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c din = new RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c(Name='sand');
        insert din;
        din.Name = 'sanc';
        update din;
        system.debug('din.id'+din.id);   

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',din.id);
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(din);
        Rfleet_GenericGridManualSolution  rp1 = new Rfleet_GenericGridManualSolution(sc);

        string selcontactid;
        selcontactid = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('recordId');

        Account Acc= New Account(Name='A1');
        insert Acc;
        RFLEET_Protocol__c Rpro=new RFLEET_Protocol__c(Name='Aggre',Rfleet_Agreement_Client__c=Acc.id,Rfleet_Status__c='Active',Rfleet_Billing_Type__c='Dossier');
        insert Rpro;
        RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c pg=new RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c(Name='t1',Rfleet_Type_of_Grid__c='Model, Version, Option - Discount%, Discount Amount, Negotiated price',Rfleet_Type_of_Sales__c='VD');
        insert pg;
        rp1.getprotocolgrid();
        rp1.getselectedContact();

        RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c  record = new RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c(Rfleet_Model__c='MAU',Rfleet_Discount__c=2.0,Rfleet_Discount_Amount__c=3.0,Rfleet_Version__c='PFG 1L323 K6',Rfleet_Option__c='test',Rfleet_Price__c=45, Rfleet_Protocol_grid_name__c=pg.id);
          Test.startTest();
        insert record;
      rp1.selectedversion='';
       rp1.selectedmodel='';    //'MAU - Nouveau Master';
      string modelandLabel=rp1.selectedmodel;
        string Splitmodelcode='';   //'MAU';
        rp1.funcGenricgrid1st();
        string Splitmodellabel=modelandLabel.substringAfter('- ');  

        string selectedversion='';  //'PFG 1L323 K6';
        rp1.funcGenricgrid1st();

       string versionandlabel='';    //'PFG 1L323 K6';
       rp1.funcGenricgrid1st();
        string Splitversioncode='';   //'PFG 1L323 K6';
        rp1.funcGenricgrid1st();
        record.Rfleet_Model__c='K12';
      update record;

        rp1.selectedmodel='tres';
       rp1.getdiscount='34';
       rp1.getdiscountamoount='';
      rp1.getprice='23'; 
       rp1.selectedversion='ver';
       rp1.funcGenricgrid1st();
       rp1.Selectedval();
        Test.stopTest(); 
     }
```

> Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 3):

The portions of your test class not covered include an If statement with what looks like 4 else statements. To cover that, you need to create 5 separate Test Methods with data that meet the criteria for each of those unique if-else statements. That's how you get coverage for those lines. Your structure would look like this:

```
@istest
Public class MyTestClass{

   Public static testMethod void MyUnitTest1(){ 

   // Create test data to pass first If condition & run remainder of test to where you can

   }

   Public static testMethod void MyUnitTest2(){ 

   // Create test data to pass 1st Else condition & run remainder of test to where you can

   }

   Public static testMethod void MyUnitTest3(){ 

   // Create test data to pass 2nd Else condition & run remainder of test to where you can

   }

   Public static testMethod void MyUnitTest4(){ 

   // Create test data to pass 3rd Else condition & run remainder of test to where you can

   }

   Public static testMethod void MyUnitTest5(){ 

   // Create test data to pass 4th Else condition & run remainder of test to where you can

   }

}
```

Comment: yes i have done similarly what you suggested but it's not covered @crmprogdev

Comment: Then you must not be creating your data test data correctly to meet the If-else conditions in the properly to match your code. OR, your code needs to be revised, which may be what your test class is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

To Cover the else statement in your code,it should meet the following criteria.

```
 selectedmodel <> ''
 getprice='';
 getdiscount <> '' or getdiscountamoount <> ''

Example
   rp1.selectedmodel='tres';
   rp1.getdiscount='34';
   rp1.getdiscountamoount='';
   rp1.getprice = '';
   rp1.funcGenricgrid1st ();
```